# Integration testing Azure Service Bus with Docker

Tags: azure, docker-compose, integration-testing, azureservicebus

What is an appropriate way to integration test systems that use ASB?  With something like Kafka and using docker-compose, I could spin up two services that will communicate asynchronously over Kafka.  Is there a way to do something similar with ASB?  If not, what is a common integration testing pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pricing model for Service Bus has [12.5 million operations per month included for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/service-bus/). Past that, it's less than a dollar per millions of messages sent. With these kinds of services it should be simple for you to spin up and tear down instances with absolutely zero cost to you as part of integration tests.

NUnit, for example provides the `[OneTimeSetup]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]` methods which you could use as part of an integration test suite to provision and subsequently delete a Service Bus instance.

Comment: I hadn't considered spinning up an "entire" Service Bus instance, but that seems like a reasonable approach.  Cost isn't the problem frankly, mostly I'm looking to isolate tests so that they don't interfere with one another and I think this approach, as does one of the other proposed answered, fits the bill.

Comment: If you're looking to perform a true "integration test" and not a unit test which mocks your dependency on the service bus, this is your best course of action.

Comment: Thanks for the corporate message, but if you go to conferences, the feedback is unanimous : tests can crash, the code can loop, the number of messages can skyrocket, and the bill can explode.
Work in progress on Microsoft side : https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/223

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I don't think [Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) supports the service bus yet, but you could extract the functionality to an interface and either write a fake ASB and use that or have the interface use the queue in the Emulator. If you want to use the actual ASB and don't mind incurring costs, you could spin up a new one with a guid for a name or if create evanescent queues or topics/subscriptions with guids for their names as well, then tear it all down when you're done.

Not ideal perhaps, but it gives you some options. Perhaps if you shared more detail about what you're using ASB for, we could offer better solutions.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea and is a concrete example of some things I was kind of thinking about.  Thank you!

Comment: These sound to me like unit tests, not integration tests. An integration test by definition should be run against an actual service and not a mock.

Comment: @JesseCarter, I see what you're saying and don't disagree.  As I dig in more, I might change my opinion, but at this point I'm interested in the interactions between two or more services and how they all "react" to one another.  I agree that not using a "real" ASB instance would yield less confidence in the test.

Comment: @ksigmund There's nothing wrong with testing the interaction between services and their interactions, this is typically what is referred to as "unit tests". I was simply answering based on your criteria of wanting to run an actual integration test which means something different. I would personally try to implement both types of tests as part of proper test coverage on an actual project

Comment: @JesseCarter I'd have a hard time calling that a unit test, but that's not to say it's not equally (or more) valuable.  I'd consider a true unit test to be testing the actual message handler, while maybe  "subcutaneous" test could exercise the service's internals by just under the application service layer.  Testing two things feels something more akin to an integration test to me, though the semantics probably don't really matter that much.

Comment: JesseCarter, a unit test is technically testing one unit or "system under test". Any test that tests the integration between 2 or more of the components is an integration test. You're talking about a full integration test. All of them can have value, but it'll be up to @ksigmund to determine what makes the most practical sense for him. Personally I would keep an ASB around for testing and create/delete the queues and topics/subscriptions on the fly. I also like to clean those up on setup, so that after a test run, I can manually inspect the deadletter queues and such, if need be.

Comment: @both discussers - Integration Tests' scope vary. With Microservices world an Integration Tests test ONE micoservice as a blackbox, with inputs and outputs controlled by the test. If ServiceBus is an input or output, we would like to have it as real as possible (e.g. Docker image in most cases). But in some scenarios this is not possible. Only then we can use a "smart mock". It's not ideal, but necessary workaround. E.g. we were testing a service that interacted with RabbitMq and a Ticketing gateway. Rabbit was a docker image in out int tests, but Ticketing system was changed into a smart mock

Answer (score 2):

There is a **Azure Storage Emulator Docker Image** in docker hub. When using it, remember that you must use Windows emulation:

[image]

given image can be used in docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    azure_sb:
        container_name: azure_sb
        image: microsoft/azure-storage-emulator
        tty: true
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"
            - "10001:10001"
            - "10002:10002"
```

For test or dev usages considec using lightway version of it which is **Azurite** [link to doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    azurite:
        container_name: azurite
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
        tty: true
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"
            - "10001:10001"
```